# Domestic accidents due to exploding plates and bowls

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a dataset that lists domestic accidents due to plates and bowls exploding due to heat or other factors, put aside direct human/animal mistake (e.g. we ignore cases where a human dropped a plate).

Ideally, it would contain the year, country, the type of materials used in the plate/bowl, the severity of the injury, and a description of the injury.